# CAS 5.2.3 & LDAP Attribute

Tags: java, ldap, single-sign-on, cas

I have CAS 5.2.3 and an LDAP connection.

LDAP has 1 domain and 2 ou (ou = groups, ou = people). Each group has a cn with the group name. Each such group contains several members, where the username from ou = people is specified.

Initially (during authentication) the user is connected to ou=people. Next, we need to get a list of its groups (one user can be in many groups) from ou=groups.

My task is to get the groups of the user when it is authenticated in order to update them.

I need to pass the user (for example: "cn=MOrlova, ou=people, dc=domain, dc=ru") and get all the groupNames of which this user is a member (Preferably in a String[ ]). The data structure is like this.

LDAP EXAMPLE:
[image: LDAP EXAMPLE]

I do not understand what settings I need to make in CAS to connect. I found these in the CAS description:

```
cas.authn.attributeRepository.ldap[2].ldapUrl=ldap://localhost:9080
cas.authn.attributeRepository.ldap[2].useSsl=false
cas.authn.attributeRepository.ldap[2].useStartTls=false
cas.authn.attributeRepository.ldap[2].connectTimeout=5000
cas.authn.attributeRepository.ldap[2].bindDn=cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=ru
cas.authn.attributeRepository.ldap[2].bindCredential=Manager1
cas.authn.attributeRepository.ldap[2].userFilter=(&(member=cn{user})
cas.authn.attributeRepository.ldap[2].subtreeSearch=true
cas.authn.attributeRepository.ldap[2].dnFormat=cn=%s,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=ru
```

Even if it works, how can I then collect the response into a list of Strings and get them in a regular Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, with this data structure, you won't be able to collect attributes.

But, there is a solution. You can create a file in *src/main/resources/META-INF/* named *spring.factories*, specify there:
`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=CasConfiguration`

Create *src/main/java/ru/security/core/cas/config* package and create *CasConfiguration* class there.

You need annotations:

```
@Configuration ("MyConfiguration")
@EnableConfigurationProperties (CasConfigurationProperties.class)
@ComponentScan ("ru.security.core.cas") //This is not necessary, but if you have other spring components, it will definitely help.
```

Next, you will have access to **CasConfigurationProperties**. We do in the *CasConfiguration* class:

```
   @Autowired
    private CasConfigurationProperties casConfigurationProperties;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory supportConnectionFactory () {
        return LdapUtils.newLdaptivePooledConnectionFactory (
                casConfigurationProperties.getAuthn().getLdap().get(0));
    }
```

Thus, we get a connection to our ldap.
Next, we need to send a request to LDAP and we can do it like this:

```
Response <SearchResult> response = null;
        try {
            response = LdapUtils.executeSearchOperation (connectionFactory, BASE_DN, LDAP_FILTER);
        } catch (LdapException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
```